# Replace text to equation in MS Word using OpenXML

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, openxml-sdk

Hello I need to replace text in my template to Mathematical equation. I want to do this by replace a paragraph or his part. I'm trying to do this with OpenXML. My program at the begining is opening a template and copy to new word document, then i'm looking in every paragraph specific words when i find it will replace whole paragraph to a new with equation. Program will compile and finish work, but when i'm trying to open a new document i can't because error appears: problem with the content.

In file ExampleXML.xml i have xml what i want to replace:

```
<?xml verios="1.0"?>
<w:p w:rsidRPr="00A750D6" w:rsidR="00212F73" w:rsidP="005437B7" w:rsidRDefault="0027760B" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
<m:oMathPara xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math">
<m:oMath>
<m:r>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math" />
    </w:rPr>
        <m:t>a=</m:t>
</m:r>
<m:f>
    <m:fPr>
        <m:ctrlPr>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math" />
                <w:i />
            </w:rPr>
        </m:ctrlPr>
    </m:fPr>
    <m:num>
        <m:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math" />
            </w:rPr>
            <m:t>c</m:t>
        </m:r>
    </m:num>
    <m:den>
        <m:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math" />
            </w:rPr>
            <m:t>b</m:t>
        </m:r>
    </m:den>
</m:f>
<m:r>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math" />
    </w:rPr>
    <m:t>*</m:t>
</m:r>
<m:rad>
    <m:radPr>
        <m:degHide m:val="1" />
        <m:ctrlPr>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math" />
                <w:i />
            </w:rPr>
        </m:ctrlPr>
    </m:radPr>
    <m:deg />
    <m:e>
        <m:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math" />
            </w:rPr>
            <m:t>a</m:t>
        </m:r>
    </m:e>
</m:rad>
</m:oMath>
</m:oMathPara>
<w:bookmarkStart w:name="_GoBack" w:id="0" />
<w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0" /></w:p>
```

This is my code:

public void CreateXmlDocument()
        {

```
        var wzor = File.ReadAllText(@"E:\ExampleXML.xml");
        using (var template = File.Open(@"E:\ExampleDOCX.docx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                template.CopyTo(stream);

                using (WordprocessingDocument WordTemplate = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
                {

                    MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart = WordTemplate.MainDocumentPart;

                    foreach (var paragraph in mainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<Paragraph>().ToList())
                    {
                        var parent = paragraph.Parent;

                        var paragraph_xml = (paragraph.OuterXml);
                        bool containsParam = false;

                        if (paragraph.InnerText.Contains("test"))
                            {
                                var tekst_replace = paragraph_xml;

                                paragraph_xml = paragraph_xml.Replace(tekst_replace, wzor);
                                containsParam = true;
                            }
                        if (containsParam)
                        {
                            parent.InsertBefore(new Paragraph(paragraph_xml), paragraph);
                            paragraph.Remove();
                        }
                    }
                    mainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
                    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                }

                using (var fileStream = File.Create(@"E:\po.docx"))
                {
                    stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What is wrong? or how can i change text to equation?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

From your snippet:

```cs
var wzor = File.ReadAllText(@"E:\ExampleXML.xml");

...

var paragraph_xml = (paragraph.OuterXml);

...

var tekst_replace = paragraph_xml;

paragraph_xml = paragraph_xml.Replace(tekst_replace, wzor);
```

It looks like this could be simplified to:

```cs
string a = "a";
string b_0 = "b";
string b_1 = b_0; // b_1 == "b"

b_0 = b_1.Replace(b_0, a); // "b".Replace("b", "a")
```

So why not just directly set `b_0 = a`?

Or in your case, replace:

```cs
var paragraph_xml = (paragraph.OuterXml);
bool containsParam = false;

if (paragraph.InnerText.Contains("test"))
{
    var tekst_replace = paragraph_xml;

    paragraph_xml = paragraph_xml.Replace(tekst_replace, wzor);
    containsParam = true;
}
if (containsParam)
{
    parent.InsertBefore(new Paragraph(paragraph_xml), paragraph);
    paragraph.Remove();
}
```

with:

```cs
if (paragraph.InnerText.Contains("test"))
{
    parent.InsertBefore(new Paragraph(wzor), paragraph);
    paragraph.Remove();
}
```